# VBA Timeout DoCmd.RunSQL Insert

Tags: sql, vba, odbc, ms-access-2007

Having a problem with a MS Access application that is throwing an ODBC connection timeout error on a `DoCmd.RunSQL` with an `insert` on a MS SQL Server linked table.

I've tried using:

```
    Dim Mydb As Database
    Set Mydb = CurrentDb
    Mydb.QueryTimeout = 900
```

per the closest MSDN I could find, but did not work.  I can `insert` into that SQL DB with less than 3-seconds query run time from SQL Management Studio, but from Access it gives this timeout.

Anyone else ran into the issue and/or found a remedy?

Comment: `ODBC connection timeout != QueryTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a pass through query for this. With the pass through query you can set the timeout option on the property sheet. It is listed as

```
ODBC Timeout
```

If you set this to 0 it will wait until the query returns records. The other great thing about the pass through query is the SQL Server is what is doing the actual work and then it returns all of the records back to Access so it runs more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the query in design view, there is a property ODBC Timeout. (Right click in blank -> Properties)
Have you tried setting it to 0 (infinite) or to a higher value?
It works for me!